# Find all the commits there are in lab branch but in master branch

Tags: git

[git-cherry](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-cherry) lets me find all the commits missing from upstream. How do I find all the commits that are there in local lab branch but not in local master branch.

```
git branch -d lab
```

Above operation fails because I have some commits not merged. I want the list of those commits that are not merged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git log master..lab` will show all commits in `lab` that aren't in `master`.

Comment: An alternative syntax (which is easier to remember) would by `git log lab --not master` or `git log lab ^master`.